# Duplicating images on scroll - is there fix without subclassing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and some items have image on the left side.

When I scroll up-down a few times image getting copied all the time to the rows that doesn't have image.
How to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Object* obj = [_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = obj.Title;

    if(obj.Image != nil){
    cell.imageView.image = obj.Image;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just adding an else statement:

```
if(obj.Image != nil)
{
    cell.imageView.image = obj.Image;
}
else
{
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: One line:
cell.imageView.image = obj.Image ? obj.Image : nil;

Comment: @rp90 That's pretty redundant.  Why not just `cell.imageView.image = obj.image`?  Then if `obj.image` is nil then the cell image gets set nil, otherwise it gets set to the image.  I was just trying to make things as readable and explanatory as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the case when obj.Image is nil explicitly. Because the cell is being reused it will also reuse its image if you don't change it.

```
if(obj.Image != nil){
    cell.imageView.image = obj.Image;
}
else
{
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```